# K6 Load Testing - Can the result be output into the Continuous Integration Pipeline?

Tags: azure, k6

We are using K6 for our load testing.

We want to add the load tests into our Continuous Integration pipeline (Microsoft Azure).

We were hoping that we could set thresholds that pass or fail the test. If the test fails, the Azure build pipeline would continue, however if the test fails the build pipeline would stop.

Can this be done in K6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is definitely possible with k6, it's actually a core use case that the tool supports. I think you'll find this Azure DevOps Pipelines guide a helpful resource:
https://k6.io/blog/integrating-load-testing-with-azure-pipelines

Reading about k6 thresholds would probably be helpful as well:
https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/thresholds

Additional links:

- Github repo with example pipeline: https://github.com/k6io/example-azure-pipelines
- Azure DevOps Pipelines extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k6.k6-load-test

Comment: where do you see the result after the running the pipeline? Does it become an artifact? Cause log is not maintainable

Answer (score 1):

It is actually the default behavior with k6! Failed thresholds cause k6 to exit with a non-zero code, which aborts the build on most CI environments.

More details: https://k6.io/blog/integrating-load-testing-with-azure-pipelines and https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/thresholds